# java path error in android studio setup for flutter while asking to review the android licenses

Tags: java, flutter, java-home

flutter doctor --android-licenses

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

i tried uninstalling jdk and installed it again but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Please check the java SDK path inside Android studio. It should be in the file-project structure menu.
Verify you have hava installed on the same path.